# How to re-export the child namespace in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, namespaces

I want to re-export the nested namespace **HTML_Validator.Localization**, but avoid the
exporting of whole **HTML_Validator**, the meged entity.

```js
class HTML_Validator {
    // ...
}


namespace HTML_Validator {

    export namespace Localization {

        export type FileIsEmptyWarningLog = Readonly<Pick<WarningLog, "title" | "description">>;

    export namespace FileIsEmptyWarningLog {
      export type NamedParameters = Readonly<{ targetFileRelativePath: string; }>;
    }

    }

}


export default HTML_Validator;
```

The re-export is required for other packages, but the functionality of **HTML_Validator** class
is not required for them - I need to export the child namespace **Localization** only.

Below code is invalid  but expesses what I want to do.

```
import HTML_Validator from "PATH/TO/HTML_Validator";
import HTML_ValidatorLocalization = HTML_Validator.Localization;

export HTML_ValidatorLocalization; // invalid: Cannot use namespace 'HTML_ValidatorLocalization' as a value.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options here:

1. Explicitly export the nested namespace
2. Extract the nested namespace

## Option 1

When working with namespaces, you can use the `import` keyword to create aliases, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#aliases. In my experience, this is one of the places where you can easily confuse (even experienced) developers, because the `import` keyword in this context is basically the equivalent of the `var` keyword - it has nothing to do with importing from modules or the like.

In your case, you can use it like so:

```js
export namespace HTML_Validator {
  export namespace Localization {
    export type FileIsEmptyWarningLog = Readonly<Pick<WarningLog, "title" | "description">>;
  
    export namespace FileIsEmptyWarningLog {
      export type NamedParameters = Readonly<{ targetFileRelativePath: string; }>;
    }
  }
}

export import Localization = HTML_Validator.Localization;
```

Now, it is possible to import the `Localization` namespace in other places using `import { Localization } from './my-html-validator';`

## Option 2

You could also explicitly extract the nested namespace, i.e. you could create a separate namespace like `HTML_Validator_Localization`, and reference it inside your `HTML_Validator` namespace. Then, similar to Option 1, you can import `HTML_Validator_Localization` using a named import from any other file.

```js
export namespace HTML_Validator {
  export import Localization = HTML_Validator_Localization;
}

export namespace HTML_Validator_Localization {
  export type FileIsEmptyWarningLog = Readonly<Pick<WarningLog, "title" | "description">>;

  export namespace FileIsEmptyWarningLog {
    export type NamedParameters = Readonly<{ targetFileRelativePath: string; }>;
  }
}
```

Again, we are using the `import` keyword here to declare the alias.

## Note

If you are using eslint, you might run into issues with the `no-unused-vars` rule. See https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/4129

Answer (score 1):

Is de-nesting the namespaces an option?  In other words, creating a `HTML_Validator_Localization` namespace in a separate file and then importing it from both existing source files?

If not, the only variation I could get the typescript compiler to accept is replacing `export HTML_ValidatorLocalization;` with `export default HTML_ValidatorLocalization;`, but that may not work in your circumstance.